# Do i need to install R in each worker node in yarn cluster in order to run SparkR?

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I'm using amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg https://github.com/amplab-extras/SparkR-pkg/blob/master/README.md. Tested and passed the run in local machine. I'm going to run it on yarn-cluster (cdh5.4). Do i need to install R in each data node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you do. Each worker has to be able to access local R interpreter.

Personally I would advise against using old SparkR though. Ignoring issues described in [SPARK-7230](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7230) it is rather unlikely that low level RDD API will ever come back to SparkR

Comment: I feel old SparkR with low level RDD is super useful. if this feature is missing with the newer apache sparkR, why stop using old SparkR then?

Comment: IMHO simply because it is not suitable for production and you have no guarantee it will work in the future. Morover there are much more robust tools in the R world.

Comment: thanks @zero323 for the expert opinions. could you please elaborate more on robust tools in R world? Do you know any other easy ways to run R in yarn-cluster?